# Macro-Enabled Template keeps opening original document when macro is run

Tags: excel, vba

I made a series of macros on a document called 'Prac.xlsm'. I then saved the document as a Macro-Enabled template. When I run the first macro in the template it works but it also opens my original document titled Prac. The macro doesn't do anything to that original document though.

I tried to step through the templates macro and that works without opening up the original.

I then tried renaming the original file which resulted in an Excel popup saying "Sorry, we couldn't find ..file path & name for the Prac file.. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?" I can't see anywhere in the code where it refers to the file name Prac.xlsm. And because stepping through the code works without opening up the original file it has me stumped.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Without the code we can't help. Please edit your qustion providing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered it was because I was accessing the macros from the ribbon as I customized it. Unsure why but if I trigger the macros from the Developer tab they work.

Comment: you probably move the template, so when you open the document it opens the original template too.
If you open the code window  (ALT+F11) you will see two templates in there.
Also, any breakpoints set in the new template to catch the startup event will never be hit...( good clue)